# How to redirect/render for a specific session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an unusual feature request where an obfuscated URL is called by a 3rd-party system, and based on that URL we want to render text **live** to a specific logged-in user.

In a controller action that is currently serving a **visitor**, how can we perform a render/redirect to a controller action serving an active **user** to render some text?

I understand there may be security concerns - we are using multiple safety checks (including unique temporary keys) to safeguard the system as much as possible.

Comment: Is this for something like a chat where the logged-in is connected via a websocket?

Comment: @max It isn't a websocket - the user is simply looking at a page on our website and we need to show them a message when we receive the verified visit.

Comment: I guess you would set it up just like any messaging system - with the exception that you let unauthenticated users create messages. If you want it to be "live" you would either need to use websockets or polling. https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples

Comment: @max Why would it not be possible to have the controller redirect to the correct action then perform a JS render? A websocket system seems like overkill for a one-off message.